# How can I accurately display numpy.timedelta64?

Tags: numpy, timedelta

As the following code makes apparent, the representation of numpy.datetime64 falls victim to overflow well before the objects fail to work.

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
def showMeDifference( t1, t2 ):
    dt      = t2-t1 
    dt64_ms = np.array( [ dt ], dtype = "timedelta64[ms]" )[0]
    dt64_us = np.array( [ dt ], dtype = "timedelta64[us]" )[0]
    dt64_ns = np.array( [ dt ], dtype = "timedelta64[ns]" )[0]
    assert( dt64_ms / dt64_ns == 1.0 )
    assert( dt64_us / dt64_ms == 1.0 )
    assert( dt64_ms / dt64_us == 1.0 )
    print str( dt64_ms )
    print str( dt64_us )
    print str( dt64_ns )


t1      = datetime.datetime( 2014, 4, 1, 12, 0, 0 )
t2      = datetime.datetime( 2014, 4, 1, 12, 0, 1 )
showMeDifference( t1, t2 )

t1      = datetime.datetime( 2014, 4, 1, 12, 0, 0 )
t2      = datetime.datetime( 2014, 4, 1, 12, 1, 0 )
showMeDifference( t1, t2 )

t1      = datetime.datetime( 2014, 4, 1, 12, 0, 0 )
t2      = datetime.datetime( 2014, 4, 1, 13, 0, 0 )
showMeDifference( t1, t2 )

print "These are for " + np.__version__
```

---

```
1000 milliseconds
1000000 microseconds
1000000000 nanoseconds
60000 milliseconds
60000000 microseconds
-129542144 nanoseconds
3600000 milliseconds
-694967296 microseconds
817405952 nanoseconds
These are for 1.7.1
```

Is this just a bug in np.timedelta64? If so, what idiom / workarounds have people used when working with np.timedelta64?

Comment: The problem appears to have been fixed as of NumPy 1.8.1.

Comment: Code does not run on 1.6.1 (divide not implemented), but even without that it probably does not show what you want. Time to upgrade Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04 ...